# cyclic mss for icu beds---help writing the code - CPLEX

Tags: cplex

The OPL model is in the code box.
My problem concerns the scheduling of the icu beds and I have a MIQP (mixed integer quadratic program)   formulation.
The goal is to level out the positive and negative deviation of the beds in intensive care,
so that the use of one bed is balanced.
For example, we want to avoid that in the first 3 days of the surgical cycle there are all occupied beds     and in the following 2 days there are all empty beds.

The problem is that Opl does not return any solution, it tells me that
-obj no value
-dneg no value
-dpos no value
I can not understand how to solve this problem.

```
      using CP;  
     
    int nspeciality=...;  //Set of clinical specialties
    int nOR=...;          //Set of surgery rooms
    int ndays=...;        //Set of days in surgery cycle
    int npazients=...;   // Set of patient types (non-ICU or ICU, I={0,1})
    int nsurgerylengthtypes=...; // Set of surgery length types (short or long)
    int ndaysinICUcycle =...;   //Set of days in ICU cycle
    int nweekend=...;       //Set of days without surgery (i.e. Saturday, Sunday)
    
    
    range speciality=0..nspeciality;
    range OR=1..nOR;
    range days=0..ndays;
    range pazients=0..npazients;
    range surgerylengthtypes=0..nsurgerylengthtypes;
    range daysinICUcycle=0..ndaysinICUcycle;
    range weekend=0..nweekend;
    
    ;
    int s[speciality][surgerylengthtypes]=...;  //Surgery duration by specialty c and length type l
    int w[OR]=...;           // Opening hours for each room r
    int p[c in speciality][i in pazients][l in surgerylengthtypes]=2*rand(10); //Number of scheduled 
                            surgeries in one surgery cycle by specialty c, patient type i, and length type l
    int N=10000;
    float randU[c in speciality][l in surgerylengthtypes][k in daysinICUcycle]=rand(N)/N; //Probability that a scheduled patient stays at least k days in the ICU after having surgery by specialty c and length type l
    
    
    float b=8.99;  //Bed utilization target level
    
    int v[speciality][OR]=...;
    int j[OR][days]=...;
    int m[c in speciality][r in OR][t in days]= v[c][r]*j[r][t]; //1 if specialty c is assigned to room r on day t; 0 otherwise
    
    dvar int dneg[days]; //Negative deviation from bed utilization target level for day t
    dvar int dpos[days]; //Positive deviation from bed utilization target level for day t
    dvar int x[speciality][OR][days][pazients][surgerylengthtypes]; //Number of assigned surgeries by specialty c, room r, day t, patient type i, length type l
    
    int h[speciality]=...;   //Maximum number of MSS blocks in one surgery cycle by specialty c
    int g[speciality]=...;   //Maximum number of daily MSS blocks by specialty c
    
    
    float y=0.25;           //Weight for positive and negative deviation from the bed utilization target level
    
    
    dexpr float obj= sum(t in days) ((y*(dneg[t])^2) + (1-y)*(dpos[t])^2);
    
    minimize obj;
    
    subject to{
   constraint_1:
     forall (c in speciality:(c-4) in speciality, r in OR, t in days)
      sum (i in pazients, l in surgerylengthtypes) s[c][l]*x[c][r][t][i][l]<= w[r]*m[c][t][r];
    
constraint_2: 
    forall(c in speciality, i in pazients, l in surgerylengthtypes)
      sum(r in OR, t in days) x[c][r][t][i][l]==p[c][i][l];
  
constraint_3: 
    forall(t in days)
      sum(c in speciality, r in OR, k in daysinICUcycle, l in surgerylengthtypes) (randU[c][l][k]*x[c][r][t][1][l]+dneg[t]-dpos[t])==b;

    constraint_4:  
    forall (c in speciality)
      sum (t in days, r in OR) m[c][r][t]<=h[c];

    constraint_5:
    forall (c in speciality, t in days)
      sum (r in OR) m[c][r][t]<=g[c];

    constraint_6:  
    forall (t in weekend)
      sum (c in speciality, r in OR) m[c][r][t]<=0;

    constraint_7:
    forall (t in days, r in OR)
      sum (c in speciality) m[c][r][t]<=1;

    constraint_8:  
    forall (t in days)
         dneg[t]>=0;

    constraint_9:    
    forall (t in days)
       dpos[t]>=0;

    constraint_10:    
    forall (c in speciality, r in OR, t in days, i in pazients, l in surgerylengthtypes)
          x[c][r][t][i][l]>0;
```

below my file .dat:

```
nspeciality=3;
nOR=4;
ndays=6;
npazients=1;
nsurgerylengthtypes=1;
ndaysinICUcycle=27;
nweekend=1;


s=[[1,1],
   [0,1],
   [1,0],
   [0,0]];
   
w=[10,8,15,9];

v=[[1,1,0,0],      
   [1,0,0,1],      
   [1,1,0,0],  
   [0,0,1,0]];
   
j=[[0,1,1,0,0,1,0],      
   [1,0,0,1,1,0,0],      
   [1,1,1,0,1,1,1],      
   [1,0,0,0,0,0,1]];
   
h=[15,18,9,20];
g=[7,8,2,10];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run in the IDE you ll see some conflicts in the conflict tab.

And then if you comment the constraints mentioned in the conflicts:

```
//    constraint_6:  
//    forall (t in weekend)
//      sum (c in speciality, r in OR) m[c][r][t]<=0;

//    constraint_7:
//    forall (t in days, r in OR)
//      sum (c in speciality) m[c][r][t]<=1;

    constraint_8:  
    forall (t in days)
         dneg[t]>=0;

    constraint_9:    
    forall (t in days)
       dpos[t]>=0;

//    constraint_10:    
//    forall (c in speciality, r in OR, t in days, i in pazients, l in surgerylengthtypes)
//          x[c][r][t][i][l]>=1;
```

then you ll get a feasible solution

NB:

Changing

```
x[c][r][t][i][l]>0;
```

to

```
x[c][r][t][i][l]>=1;
```

will make your model both work with MIP and CP.